# webpack - how to stop the loader running twice?

Tags: javascript, webpack

All of my text imports in a big project are in the form:

`var template = require('text!./foo.html');`

I'd like to set webpack to automatically use text-loader, so I added the following to my config:

`{ test: /\.html$/, loader: 'text-loader' }`

Only problem is now my templates are being run through the loader twice, and I'm getting something like this in my bundle...

`module.exports = 'module.exports = "<section class=\\"foobar\\" ...`

How can I set the loader to only run once without removing all of the `text!` callouts from every one of my files? This isn't an option as I'm trying to migrate incrementally...

Comment: try this `{ test: /\.html$/, loader: 'text-loader!!' }` the exclamation marks might stop the subsequent loaders, but its not clear from the docs how this might work with config loaders and inline loaders.  https://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html

Answer (score 3):

`require('text!./foo.html')` applies `text-loader` to the `foo.html`
`{ test: /\.html$/, loader: 'text-loader' }` applies `text-loader` to `every html` 
Hence,your loader is applied twice.

You should remove `text-loader` from either of two and it will work fine